# how to send data fron service to receiver android

Tags: android, android-intent

i`m trying to send data from a service to receiver 
this is the servce's  onCreate method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("latitude", "2");
intent.putExtra("longitude", "3");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 50 * 10000, pendingIntent);
```

and this is the receive's  onReceive method

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Repeating Alarm worked. latitude: "+intent.getStringExtra("latitude")+"  longitude "+intent.getStringExtra("latitude"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and i have another activity that run the service .. the problem is when i run my app the dtata that i send from the service to the receiver is null.

thanx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

For the intent extras, I thing you should put the latitude and longitude in a persistent storage, and when you receive a broadcast you take them from the storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) in Service communications.

In your Service you send the information via Local broadcast like in this example: [LocalBroadCastExample](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Using-LocalBroadcastManager-in-Service-to-Activity-Communications.aspx)